# Correct way to put all asynchronous operations of an object into a boost::asio::strand

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The official Boost.Asio tutorial https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html demonstrates how one can use the `boost::asio::bind_executor` function that returns a new handler that automatically dispatches its contained completion handler through the strand object:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Printer1
{
public:
Printer1(boost::asio::io_context& io)
: m_strand{boost::asio::make_strand(io)}
, m_timer1{io}
, m_timer2{io}
{
    m_timer1.async_wait(boost::asio::bind_executor(m_strand, [this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "1 ";}));
    m_timer2.async_wait(boost::asio::bind_executor(m_strand, [this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "2 ";}));
}
private:
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> m_strand;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer1;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer2;
};
```

Now lets assume that one wants to put all operations of the timers into the same strand.

Would

```cpp
class Printer2
{
public:
Printer2(boost::asio::io_context& io)
: m_strand{boost::asio::make_strand(io)}
, m_timer1{m_strand}
, m_timer2{m_strand}
{
    m_timer1.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "1 ";});
    m_timer1.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "2 ";});
}
private:
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> m_strand;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer1;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer2;
};
```

or

```cpp
class Printer3
{
public:
template <typename Executor>
Printer3(Executor executor)
: m_timer1{executor}
, m_timer2{executor}
{
    m_timer1.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "1 ";});
    m_timer1.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& error){std::cout << "2 ";});
}
private:
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer1;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer2;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    Printer3 p{boost::asio::make_strand(io)};
    // ...
}
```

do the job?

Comment: I really do wonder what folks are voting to close this, specifically because "it needs details or clarity"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one can use the boost::asio::bind_executor function that returns a new handler that automatically dispatches its contained completion handler through the strand object

It doesn't create a handler that "automatically dispatches". Instead, it decorates the handler with information that **allows** the library code to correctly dispatch to the associated executor.

> Q. would `Printer2` or `Printer3` do the job?

Yes. Both do the job, because the `async_wait` operation invokes the handler on the *default executor of the IO object* unless the handler has been associated with a different one.

Simplified all of the examples:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11cb100858a6d7e8)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static inline auto handler(int id) {
    static auto constexpr now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const start   = now();
    return [=](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        std::cout                                             //
            << std::setw(6) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " //
            << id << " (" << ec.message() << ")"              //
            << std::endl;
    };
}

struct Test1 {
    Test1(asio::io_context& io) : m_ex{make_strand(io)} {
        t1.async_wait(bind_executor(m_ex, handler(1)));
        t2.async_wait(bind_executor(m_ex, handler(2)));
    }

  private:
    asio::any_io_executor m_ex;
    asio::steady_timer t1{m_ex, 100ms}, t2{m_ex, 200ms};
};

struct Test2 {
    Test2(asio::io_context& io) : m_ex{make_strand(io)} {
        t1.async_wait(handler(3));
        t2.async_wait(handler(4));
    }

  private:
    asio::any_io_executor m_ex;
    asio::steady_timer t1{m_ex, 300ms}, t2{m_ex, 400ms};
};

struct Test3 {
    template <typename Ex> Test3(Ex ex) : t1{ex, 500ms}, t2{ex, 600ms} {
        t1.async_wait(handler(5));
        t2.async_wait(handler(6));
    }

  private:
    asio::steady_timer t1, t2;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Test1 t1{ioc};
    Test2 t2{ioc};
    Test3 t3{make_strand(ioc)};

    ioc.run();
}
```

Prints

```
   100ms 1 (Success)
   200ms 2 (Success)
   300ms 3 (Success)
   400ms 4 (Success)
   500ms 5 (Success)
   600ms 6 (Success)
```

The third one has a distinct benefit of not hardcoding the executor type, which is beneficial in case you... use a different kind of context. Like, for example one that uses a thread pool.

To avoid templating the constructor, consider using the default type-erased executor type used by all IO objects:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/529e718ace006615)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Ultimate {
    Ultimate(asio::any_io_executor ex) : t1{ex, 1s}, t2{ex, 2s} {
        std::cout << std::unitbuf;
        t1.async_wait([](error_code) { std::cout << "1 "; });
        t2.async_wait([](error_code) { std::cout << "2 "; });
    }

  private:
    asio::steady_timer t1, t2;
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc;

    Ultimate t3{make_strand(ioc)};

    ioc.join();
}
```

[image]