# How can I let the asio eventloop call a lambda from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

Assume a thread is running the asio event loop, how can I defer a lambda to be called in this thread?

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>


int main()
{
    asio::io_context io_context;
    // hook something into io_context
    std::jthread t([&]{io_context.run();});
    // now how to let eventoop thread call lambda
    io_context.async_call([]{std::cout<<"Hello World!";}); // this method does not exist
}
```

I am looking for a functionality in the spirit of http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/async.html#c.uv_async_t, in libuv this is possible with `uv_async_send` these guarantees:

- > Async handles allow the user to “wakeup” the event loop and get a
  > callback called from another thread.
- > It’s safe to call this function from any thread. The callback will be
  > called on the loop thread.
- > uv_async_send() is async-signal-safe. It’s safe to call this function
  > from a signal handler.

What would be the equivalent in asio?

Comment: Regarding async signal safety, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/signals.html which allows you to post any operations/handlers from the completion handler to the async signal wait

Comment: @sehe What would happen if I posted from a signal handler registered with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal ?

Comment: That's not supported. But Asio abstracts it all away safely behind the `signal_set` service object. Including defined semantics in fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asio you post[1] work to an executor.

The executor is associated with an execution context. In your example `io_context` is such an execution context.

So, you would say:

```
asio::post(io_context.get_executor(), []{std::cout<<"Hello World!";});
```

ADL makes it so that you can probably use unqualified:

```
post(io_context.get_executor(), []{std::cout<<"Hello World!";});
```

Next up, as a convenience Asio supports posting “to” an execution context, in which case its default executor will be used:

```
post(io_context, []{std::cout<<"Hello World!";});
```

### Differences

If you use `asio::dispatch` the posted handler **may be** invoked on the calling thread *iff* the executor matches that thread. E.g. in the given example `asio::dispatch` would behave just like `asio::post` unless you used it from inside a handler already running on the “service thread” (a thread running the io context).

### Associated Executors

There are multiple types of executors. They might add custom behavior. For example `strand<>` executors make sure only a single handler runs concurrently, enabling you to get serialization of access similarly to mutual exclusion in synchronous code.

It stands to reason the choice of executor will be important for this mechanism to be correct. The library has an “associated executor” facility to allow it to honor executor requirements correctly in generic code.

For example, composed operations (like `asio::async_read_until`) will correctly use the associated executor even for any intermediate handlers that it posts internally.

To associate an executor, use `bind_executor`, e.g.:

**[Live On Colriu](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c0bcabc5caaab04)**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool tp; // multi threading execution context
    auto strand = make_strand(tp.get_executor()); // using a strand to serialize handlers

    auto handler = [&strand] { std::cout << "On the strand: " << strand.running_in_this_thread() << std::endl; };
    auto bound = bind_executor(strand, handler);

    // Now even posting _without_ an executor will invoke the bound handler on the intended executor:
    post(bound);

    tp.join();
}
```

Which prints

```
On the strand: 1
```

See for more related information:

- [boost::asio::bind_executor does not execute in strand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475533/boostasiobind-executor-does-not-execute-in-strand/71475865)
- [Correct way to put all asynchronous operations of an object into a boost::asio::strand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630192/correct-way-to-put-all-asynchronous-operations-of-an-object-into-a-boostasio/75632626)
- [Which io_context does std::boost::asio::post / dispatch use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458609/which-io-context-does-stdboostasiopost-dispatch-use/52460852)
- [What is the difference between post and dispatch from boost::asio when overloads with executor parameter are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581761/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-dispatch-from-boostasio-when-overloads/76584453)

More related to the core execution guarantees of the library:

- [ASIO: Is it defined behavior to run a completion handler in a different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447160/asio-is-it-defined-behavior-to-run-a-completion-handler-in-a-different-thread/72454370)

[1] `asio::post`, `asio::defer`, `asio::dispatch`

Comment: Made my live demo working :) https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c0bcabc5caaab04  Struggling hard because of mobile device keyboards